# How to Escape a 1x2 Hole with Villager?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Help!  I'm stuck in a 1x2 hole with a villager.  The hitbox of the villager takes up the whole range of area that I can hit unless I jump.  I have no tools because I was on a trading run, so my inventory is almost empty.  This is one of my favorite villagers because I have some really good trades setup.  Is there any way to get out of this hole without killing the villager or killing myself?

[image: Stuck in a hole with Villager]

Comment: interesting predicerment. Can you use console commands to teleport away? I'm pretty sure such commands excist although I do not know them offhand. You could also use a 3rd party program to edit the area, giving you a way out.

Comment: Do villagers heal damage? If so, you could do a couple of hits to a dirt block, wait for the villager to heal, repeat as necessary. (Assuming dirt blocks don't *also* heal...) Of course, even it it doesn't kill him, I don't know how pissed-off he'll be...

Comment: When this has happened to me, I was able to chop the adjacent wood block away.  Is the "hitbox" different for hands vs. tools?

Comment: @Cyclops I never would have phrased it that way, but since you did… Yes, dirt blocks "heal" if you stop hitting them before they break. ^^

Comment: I've actually had this problem and did eventually manage to dig my way out. I had to hit the villager to make them "bounce" out of the way though, and that was before being victims of battery made them sad.

Comment: This isn't really important, but how on earth did you manage that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are a few ways out if you just happen to have the right items still left in your pared-down inventory:

- A [sand](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sand) or [gravel](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Gravel) block: You can jump up and place blocks around and above the hole so that one of these blocks falls through you into the bottom of the hole. You can then jump up onto it to get out. Be sure to only drop **one** block for you and your villager to jump up on since two will suffocate you.
- A [water source block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Water) (i.e. [water bucket](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bucket)): You can place this outside the hole so that it flows into the hole, then swim up the waterfall. Be sure to pick the source up quickly after you swim out so your villager doesn't risk drowning.
- A [boat](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Boat), [minecart](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecart), or [bed](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed): You can jump and place these outside the hole, then jump again to right-click on them, which will place you inside/on them and safely out of the hole. If you don't have any of these, but you **do** have the materials to craft them (along with a [crafting table](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Crafting_Table)), then you can jump up to place a crafting table outside, jump up to right-click on it, and then make what you need.
- An [Ender Pearl](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Pearl): Jumping up and throwing it will teleport you out of the hole. If you're patient you could even wait until night to lure a passing Enderman over and kill it for one.
- Saddled pig rescue: If there's a saddled pig nearby, or a nearby pig you could [saddle](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Saddle), then jumping up and right-clicking on it will also get you out.

If you don't happen to have any of these items, I think your only hope is to position yourself just right so you can dig away at a wall block without hitting the villager's hitbox. Of course, you could also wait until you get killed by mobs or starve to death, then just respawn and return to free your villager.

Comment: +1 Excellent ideas :) I did not have any of the items in my inventory you mentioned (I had basically a sword and food because I filled my inventory with charcoal for trading).  I did end up succeeding after about 10 minutes to find just the right sweet spot, at about the junction between the bottom and top block, where I could actually hit it with my hand and successfully break it without hitting the villager.  In the past in a similar situation, I have actually been able to get out with my trusty Efficiency IV diamond shovel, because I could just break the block while jumping.

Comment: Needless to say, I now put blocks two above the head of all my villagers I have temporarily "stored" in holes to prevent myself from falling in.

Answer (score 14):

You can also open your world to LAN and join from another Minecraft copy and literally help yourself out.

Comment: with no supplies in his inventory, this is the only real solution.

Comment: It may just be my perfectionism / OCD speaking through, but I absolutely *loathe* any method of getting out of a predicament that requires "cheating".  I have multiple NB editing tools and map editors that I could have easily used to move my position out of the hole, but I won't allow myself to use them in my active survival worlds.

Answer (score 7):

I know the user in question has since been freed, but there's an excellent and guaranteed solution in case this ever happens in the future. It does not require any inventory items whatsoever.

If you're in the middle of mining a block, coming in contact with an entity (such as a villager or cow) will stop the mining but not attack the entity. This makes it so if you're mining you don't accidentally attack anything you don't want to.

To get out of the hole:

1. Jump and hold left click while aiming at a grass block. When you land, you'll most likely stop mining since you're inside the villager's hitbox.
2. Move around while holding the left click button until you find a spot where you can mine a dirt block long enough to pick it up and escape.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a water bucket? You can use that to get out.

Answer (score 0):

13 blocks down with a villager:
I used water in one hand and sand in the other. I dropped the sand over us then jumped on top of the block when it settled, then placed water on the sand to get the villager to jump out of the sand block. Put the water back in bucket and repeat the above sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Villagers can now be given armor (though it does not show up on their model).  Throw them your armor and you won't have to worry about killing them while trying to mine.  However, you can't get your armor back without killing them.